How to implement drag limits between multiple canvas?
I need to make the "signer-box" element move between pages, so that it is completely on the other canvas when it is moved, simulating a page change of the element, it can move to another page, but it cannot keep the part outside the element as in the image below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17-dragdrop-thq7pu


